# Remove weird characters on windows command line

Tags: windows, laravel, console

Does anyone know how can I disable these weird characters on my command line? I can't remember what I have done but this keeps on showing now on my command line.

[image]

Comment: did you changed your locale..? looks like IME gone insane..

Comment: It looks like the app is trying to output ANSI terminal control codes (which Windows Console subsystem does not understand). Depending on the app there may be settings (eg. setting environment variable `TERM` to `msys` is used in Git).

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, maybe someone naively assumed that this means the console's virtual terminal mode is enabled. This feature is disabled by default in Windows 10. Console applications have to call `GetConsoleMode`, enable the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag, and set the mode via `SetConsoleMode`. If setting the mode fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, then VT mode isn't supported on the current system.

Comment: The weird characters are spaces and line endings I believe.

Comment: No, they're [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), which is a way to control the console with inline commands written to the screen buffer. The question mark glyph in the screen capture is the "\x1b" escape character (ESC). For example, `ESC[34;4m` makes the foreground text blue (34) and underlined (4). The console in Windows 10 supports VT sequences, but it's disabled by default. In older versions of Windows you can use ANSICON or ConEmu to get VT support.